# Eclipse console terminates codes

Tags: java, eclipse

so i was doing some excercises(i won't go into details since it's not important) for Java and when i try to run this code here:

```
for(int i = 1;i == myInt;i++){//myInt is a pre-entered integer using Scanner
        int a = myInt % i;
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

the console ternimate it and display nothing.when i changed the code to this:

```
for(int i = 1;i < myInt;i++){
        int a = myInt % i;
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

the console display a list of "a" normally.I want to know what's wrong with the first code.I'm using eclipse,java 8 btw.

Comment: Your first loop will run as long as the condition (`i==myInt`) is true. If it is not true in the first iteration (i.e. if `myInt` is not 1), it won't run at all. That is what the condition in a `for` loop does.

Comment: ok,ty so much for your answer.I understand why it's not running now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first for loop will go through while i is equal to myInt. So if myInt is anything other than 1, the for loop will be skipped.

Comment: ty for your answer.I understand now.